# Displaying the users information from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to created a way to call information from the database for a user to view. Such as they log in and it has their registered information viewed. I have this

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['id'])
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE `id` = $_SESSION[id]")
or die(mysql_error());  

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
 echo '<b>First Name:</b>' .$row['fname'];
 echo '<br>';
 echo '<b>Last Name:</b>' .$row['lname'];
 }
```

but nothing shows up. My database name is megan, table is user, fields i want displayed are first name (fname) and last name (lname).
Can someone point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance!

Comment: PHP's `ext/mysql` (the `mysql_*` family) is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  Please use [something else](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Bad array indexing.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE `id` = " . $_SESSION['id'])
```

You should turn on PHP error displaying.

Answer (score 0):

First change this,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
```

because you have to check if the session isset correctly then do the query,

then the sql change to this,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE `id` = ".$_SESSION['id'])
```

Comment: Thank you, but nothing prints to screen